# How to live-reload node.js(Express) server with react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, livereload

**Hi there**,
I having some problems with back-end of my project.
Bascily I'm using  *create-react-app*  as my boilerplate and trying to attach server on  *express*  with  *socket.io* . I did some tutorials etc. But all of those servers based on build version of my app. I'm trying to find solution where I can code on react files and see result on my server same time,  **not rebuilding whole app each time** I made any changes to it.

Here is git with project:
https://github.com/7sleepwalker/boilerplate_server

At the moment I have: 
 server runing at localhost:3001 (based on build files of app)
production app runing at localhost:3000
Any ideas how to join both?